# Where else for help on English Reasoning Questions?

Tags: discussion

If [StackExchange offers no other helpful site](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/8712), would you please suggest free, online sources of help?

Sadly, I live in an area with barely any native English speakers, and likely no person who has succeeded in these kinds of English reasoning tests. I can't find anyone who can help with my questions, even aside from the fact that my low income doesn't support costly private tutoring.

Yet can my current questions be improved or rephrased to focus on English and logic? Or is the problem the quantity of these questions? What can I do, in return? Sadly, my English is flawed so I generally let skilled Anglophones answer. I've always appreciated invaluable help from ELL, which I hope can be applied to benefit everyone, and not just me, even though my questions may seem localised.

Update: Thank you effusively for the helpful comments so far. I thought to specify that it's recommended to ignore the LSAT., because it differs from the UK [LNAT](http://www.lnat.ac.uk/) (what I'm trying to prepare for).

Comment: [Logic is the study of formal systems of reasoning, especially of the deductive variety.](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) So you might try Stack Exchange ***philosophy*** for questions where the issue is more one of *reasoning* than the meaning of the actual words.

Comment: For reading comprehension, I think the ask "a question get an answer" format of StackExchange might not be the best fit. I think a discussion forum would be much more helpful, particularly if you can find other folks like yourself online that are studying for either the LNAT or the LSAT (which is the American version). I did a quick search for online study groups and forums and didn't have much luck. Maybe someone else could recommend a way to connect with other people studying for the same test.

Comment: @LePressentiment, I agree with ColleenV that what you want is a community of your peers, who share a common objective (passing the LNAT), and a more fluid, informal format than StackExchange offers.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any such site personally, but if there's one thing I know about the internet, it's there's a forum for *everything*. I'll also suggest that your questions have less to do with English, *per se*, than analysis and reasoning; to that end, it might help you to try to translate the passages to your native language first, then answer them.

Comment: I think one of the issues is that, as I mentioned in your other meta post, these questions are like proofreading, which is the ELL/ELU equivalent of **too localised**. It's not just the type of question, but the volume of questions of the same form.

Comment: Does your area have French reasoning tests?  (For example, for admission to colleges or law schools.)  Kaplan is an American company that offers "SAT prep", "LSAT prep", and other courses to help people prepare for English reasoning tests.  Does your area have a similar company for tests in your native language?

Comment: @Jasper No, I must write this LNAT test that's in English.

Comment: @LePressentiment -- Verbal reasoning skills are a transferable skill.  If you improve your ability to take the LSAT, you will improve your ability to take the LNAT.  Similarly, if you improve your ability to take French verbal reasoning tests, you will improve your ability to take the LNAT.  With luck, the verbal reasoning you do in law school will be similar enough that what you learn will help with law school, too.

Comment: *The Bell Curve* by Richard Herrnstein and Charles Murray is an excellent overview of the extent to which reasoning skills are teachable (or not), and overlap (or not) between different kinds of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some forum posts on ["The Student Room"](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/search.php?filter%5Bforumid%5D=%28225%29&sortby=date+desc&s=&securitytoken=guest&f=225&query=lnat) regarding LNAT.

I don't know if it would be the resource you are looking for. But you may get better suggestions of direction or advice by signing up and asking the people there what they know about.

There are numerous free legal Q&A sites online which also may not be the forum for your questions...but be okay to ask the question about where you might find the right forum.

http://www.lawguru.com/

http://www.lawqa.com/

etc.  Although it seems a lot of the lawyers are from the US and might not have UK connections who would know, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

*(Well sometimes the Internet makes it hurt to ask, if you allow it to.)*